# Show that the following graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have the following problem to resolve:

> If $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $V$ is the set of all the subsets of 2
>   elements of $X$. If $A$ is the set of pairs of elements of $V$ that are
>   disjoint  (as subsets of $X$). Show that the graph $G=(V,A)$ is
>   isomorphic to the graph shown below:
>
> [image: Graph]

From this, we know that:

$$X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

And from what I understand:

$$
V=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,1\}\{...\}\}
$$

But this seems incorrect  as since $X$ appears to be representing the nodes of the graph, that set of subsets above would be $A$ and here is where I start getting confused.

Any suggestions on better understanding the concept of the problem and at the same time the steps in resolving it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph). The set of vertices are the two element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and two vertices are adjacent iff they are disjoint as sets. For example there is an edge between $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ (since $\{1,2\}\cap \{3,4\}=\varnothing$ but not an edge between $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ (since $\{1,2\}\cap \{2,3\}\neq\varnothing$). This graph has $\binom{5}{2}=10$ vertices.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to label the vertices and observe that the edges are "disjoint pairs". It is of course the Petersen graph.

[image]

Comment: Could you help me ton understand the concept behind the labels?

Comment: @OmariCelestine The vertices are the two element subsets of $[5]$ and pairs are joined if they are disjoint (have no common elements). So $\{1,2 \}$ is joined to $\{3,4 \}$ etc ... You just need to show that the vertices of your graph can be labelled by these $2-$sets and that the edges satisfy the "disjoint" criteria. $\ddot \smile$